# Retrieve transaction id paypal

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I create a recurring payment by using paypal express checkout without call DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Do you know how can I get transaction ID after created Recurring Profile?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, the recurring payment profile will not be created and thus will not have a Transaction ID associated with it.

The transaction ID will be returned in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment response.

Comment: Thank you, but if I call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, buyer is charged 2 times. How can I solve it?

Comment: When setting up the profile, you may be setting a one-time payment and then setting the recurring payments profile to start today. You would want to set the profile to start charging in one month from today (or week, 6mo...whatever your cycle is)